# How to find 10 values, exponentially distributed, which sum to a value, x

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I have a value, for example 2.8. I want to find 10 numbers which are on an exponential curve, which sum to this value.

That is, I want to end up with 10 numbers which sum to 2.8, and which, when plotted, look like the curve below (exponential decay). These 10 numbers should be equally spaced along the curve - that is, the 'x-step' between the values should be constant.

[image: Exponential Decrease]

This value of 2.8 will be entered by the user, and therefore the way I calculate this needs to be some kind of algorithm that I can program (hence asking this on SO not Math.SE).

I have no idea where to start with this at all - any ideas?

Comment: How are you drawing numbers on a graph? A graph consists of pairs of numbers, not just numbers. Your y values are the 10 numbers but what are the x values?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to do this with x values from 1 to 10. Does that help?

Comment: @robintw: With given x values, the y values are already fixed (e^-1, e^-2, ...), no? Or can you scale the curve? In that case, your problem would be trivial.

Comment: @undur_gongor - I can scale the curve, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have 10 x values equally distributed, i.e. x_k = a + k * b. They shall fulfill sum(exp(-x_k)) = v with v being your target value (the 2.8). This means exp(-a) * sum(exp(-b)^k) = v.

Obviously, there is a solution for each choice of b if v is positive. Set b to an arbitrary value, and calculate a from it.

E.g. for v = 2.8 and b = 0.1, you get a = -log(v / sum(exp(-b)^k)) = -log(2.8/sum(0.90484^k)) = -log(2.8/6.6425) = -log(0.421526) = 0.86387.

So for this example, the x values would be 0.86387, 0.96387, ..., 1.76387 and the y values 0.421526, 0.381412, 0.345116, 0.312274, 0.282557, 0.255668, 0.231338, 0.209324, 0.189404, 0.171380.

**Update:**

As it has been clarified that the curve can be scaled arbitrarily and the xs are preferred to be 1, 2, 3 ... 9, this is much more simple.

Assuming the curve function is r*exp(-x), the 10 values would be r*exp(-1) ... r*exp(-9). Their sum is r*sum(exp(-x)) = r*0.58190489. So to reach a certain value (2.8) you just have to adjust the r accordingly:

r = 2.8/sum(exp(-x)) = 4.81178294

And you get the 10 values: 1.770156, 0.651204, 0.239565, 0.088131, 0.032422, 0.011927, 0.004388, 0.001614, 0.000594.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to find `x` which solves the equation

[image]

It can be solved as

[image]

(just sum numbers as geometric progression)

The equation under `RootOf` will always have 1 real square different from 1 for 2.8 or any other positive number. You can solve it using some [root-finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) algorithm (1 is always a root but it does not solve original task).  For  constant `a` you can choose any number you like.

After computing the `x` you can easily calculate 10 numbers as [image].

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to generalize and assume you want N numbers summing to V.

Since your numbers are equally spaced on an exponential you can write your sum as

```
a + a*x + a*x^2 + ... + a*x^(N-1) = V
```

Where the first point has value `a`, and the second `a*x` etc.

You can take out a factor of `a` and get:

```
a ( 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^(N-1) ) = V
```

If we're free to pick `x` then we can solve for a easily

```
a = V / ( 1 + x + x^2 + .. x^(N-1) ) 
  = V*(x+1)/(x^N-1)
```

Substituting that back into

```
a, a*x, a*x^2, ..., a*x^(N-1)
```

gives the required sequence